How to extract song lyrics from an m4a subtitle stream?
I have these .m4a files for which ffprobe (on Debian 12.1) reports:
  Stream #0:1[0x2](eng): Data: bin_data (text / 0x74786574), 0 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SubtitleHandler
Unsupported codec with id 98314 for input stream 1

Are those song lyrics, and if so, how can I extract them as plain text?

They are, mostly likely, chapter markers.
I was looking for bin_data initially, but everything I'd find was:
Stream #0:1(eng): Data: bin_data (tx3g / 0x67337874) 

But finding this post gave me a similar file to test with.
Then, searching for bin_data (text...) landed me at this post on superuser.com:
ffmpeg -i input_movie.mov -map 0:d:0 -c copy -f data text.bin

[mjpeg @ 0x555d72be4000] EOI missing, emulating
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'test.m4a':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : M4V 
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: M4A mp42isom
    creation_time   : 2019-02-20T23:54:27.000000Z
    title           : FS232 Wurstkatastrophe im Bällebad
    artist          : Metaebene Personal Media
    album           : Freak Show
    track           : 232
    date            : 2019
    encoder         : auphonic.com
    iTunSMPB        :  00000000 00000800 000005E0 00000000125EC620 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
    description     : 
    comment         : 
    album_artist    : Freak Show
  Duration: 03:52:57.53, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1 kb/s
  Chapters:
    Chapter #0:0: start 0.000000, end 65.487000
      Metadata:
        title           : Intro
    Chapter #0:1: start 65.487000, end 169.929000
      Metadata:
        title           : Begrüßung
    Chapter #0:2: start 169.929000, end 397.296000
      Metadata:
        title           : Niklas Roy
    Chapter #0:3: start 397.296000, end 1603.783000
      Metadata:
        title           : Heimcomputer und Spielekonsolen
    Chapter #0:4: start 1603.783000, end 3173.700000
      Metadata:
        title           : Grafiksoftware
    Chapter #0:5: start 3173.700000, end 4836.552000
      Metadata:
        title           : Kunst
    Chapter #0:6: start 4836.552000, end 6757.380000
      Metadata:
        title           : Niklas' Projekte
    Chapter #0:7: start 6757.380000, end 8316.623000
      Metadata:
        title           : Steuerung und Workshops
    Chapter #0:8: start 8316.623000, end 10261.220000
      Metadata:
        title           : Dokumentation und freie Lizenzen
    Chapter #0:9: start 10261.220000, end 13145.059000
      Metadata:
        title           : Neues aus Barcelona
    Chapter #0:10: start 13145.059000, end 13661.674000
      Metadata:
        title           : E-Roller Security
    Chapter #0:11: start 13661.674000, end 13857.677000
      Metadata:
        title           : Free Wifi an Flughäfen
    Chapter #0:12: start 13857.677000, end 13977.530000
      Metadata:
        title           : Ausklang
  Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Audio: aac (HE-AAC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 47 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-02-20T23:54:27.000000Z
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:1[0x2](eng): Data: bin_data (tx3g / 0x67337874)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-02-20T23:58:55.000000Z
      handler_name    : "Chapter Titles"
  Stream #0:2[0x3](eng): Video: mjpeg (Baseline) (jpeg / 0x6765706A), yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 300x300 [SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1], 0.0001 fps, 0.0001 tbr, 1k tbn (default) (attached pic) (timed thumbnails)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-02-20T23:58:55.000000Z
      handler_name    : "Chapter Images"
      vendor_id       : ....
Output #0, data, to 'text.bin':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : M4V 
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: M4A mp42isom
    album_artist    : Freak Show
    title           : FS232 Wurstkatastrophe im Bällebad
    artist          : Metaebene Personal Media
    album           : Freak Show
    track           : 232
    date            : 2019
    comment         : 
    iTunSMPB        :  00000000 00000800 000005E0 00000000125EC620 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
    description     : 
    encoder         : Lavf60.16.100
  Chapters:
    Chapter #0:0: start 0.000000, end 65.487000
      Metadata:
        title           : Intro
    Chapter #0:1: start 65.487000, end 169.929000
      Metadata:
        title           : Begrüßung
    Chapter #0:2: start 169.929000, end 397.296000
      Metadata:
        title           : Niklas Roy
    Chapter #0:3: start 397.296000, end 1603.783000
      Metadata:
        title           : Heimcomputer und Spielekonsolen
    Chapter #0:4: start 1603.783000, end 3173.700000
      Metadata:
        title           : Grafiksoftware
    Chapter #0:5: start 3173.700000, end 4836.552000
      Metadata:
        title           : Kunst
    Chapter #0:6: start 4836.552000, end 6757.380000
      Metadata:
        title           : Niklas' Projekte
    Chapter #0:7: start 6757.380000, end 8316.623000
      Metadata:
        title           : Steuerung und Workshops
    Chapter #0:8: start 8316.623000, end 10261.220000
      Metadata:
        title           : Dokumentation und freie Lizenzen
    Chapter #0:9: start 10261.220000, end 13145.059000
      Metadata:
        title           : Neues aus Barcelona
    Chapter #0:10: start 13145.059000, end 13661.674000
      Metadata:
        title           : E-Roller Security
    Chapter #0:11: start 13661.674000, end 13857.677000
      Metadata:
        title           : Free Wifi an Flughäfen
    Chapter #0:12: start 13857.677000, end 13977.530000
      Metadata:
        title           : Ausklang
  Stream #0:0(eng): Data: bin_data (tx3g / 0x67337874)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-02-20T23:58:55.000000Z
      handler_name    : "Chapter Titles"
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[out#0/data @ 0x555d72bf14c0] video:0kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.000000%
size=       0kB time=03:50:57.67 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s speed=3.19e+05x    

Upon seeing the output of the text.bin track, we've discovered it's chapter markers, not lyrics, unfortunately.  I looked at text.bin itself and it shows:
fedora@/dev/pts/0:$ cat text.bin
Intro
     Begrüßung
Niklas RoyHeimcomputer und SpielekonsolenGrafiksoftwareKunstNiklas' ProjekteSteuerung und Workshops Dokumentation und freie LizenzenNeues aus BarcelonaE-Roller SecurityFree Wifi an FlughäfeAusklang

Which seems to line up with the chapter output.

I have no idea what the encoding for that file is, but if you want the metadata properly output to a file:
#!/bin/bash

ffmpeg -i your_file.m4a -map 0:d -c copy -f data text.bin > ffoutput.log 2>&1

line1=$(cat ffoutput.log | grep -n 'data.bin' | cut -d':' -f1)
line2=$(cat ffoutput.log | grep -n 'Stream mapping' | cut -d':' -f1)

tail -n +$line1 | head -n $((line2-line1)) > chapters.txt

cat chapters.txt

That will output the text between Output #0, data, to 'text.bin': and
Stream mapping: from the ffmpeg log.
